# json data value type

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to change json array values from strings to float values which from php script. It's all string type. I want it as a float type.

```
[{"year":"2008","value":"4169.20"},
{"year":"2009","value":"4067.50"},
{"year":"2010","value":"4848.40"},
{"year":"2011","value":"5654.80"},
{"year":"2012","value":"6071.50"}]
```

But i want it to look like. Is it possible?

```
[{"year":"2008","value":4169.20},
{"year":"2009","value":4067.50},
{"year":"2010","value":4848.40},
{"year":"2011","value":5654.80},
{"year":"2012","value":6071.50}]
```

Comment: When you are generating the JSON data, put the `value` as type `float`.

Comment: Loop over the array and call `parseFloat()` on the `value` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to cast `value` to float before encoding data to the JSON.

But if you want to work only in JS:

```
var data = [ /* your data */ ];

data.forEach(function(item){
  item.value = +item.value;
});
```

Output:

```
[
  {"year":"2008","value":4169.2},
  {"year":"2009","value":4067.5},
  {"year":"2010","value":4848.4},
  {"year":"2011","value":5654.8},
  {"year":"2012","value":6071.5}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data = '[{"year":"2008","value":"4169.20"},
{"year":"2009","value":"4067.50"},
{"year":"2010","value":"4848.40"},
{"year":"2011","value":"5654.80"},
{"year":"2012","value":"6071.50"}]';

$a = json_decode($data);
$b = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $v) {
 $c['year'] = $v->year;
 $c['value'] = (float) $v->value;
 $b[] = $c;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_encode($b));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/AVKC7rFY)

Answer (score 0):

use javascript parseFloat() function:

e.g.

```
var b = parseFloat("10.00")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see only JS answers. I don't know what is your intention, but if you have the jsong string in PHP you can use something like this:

```
$json = ' [
    {"year":"2008","value":"4169.20"},
    {"year":"2009","value":"4067.50"},
    {"year":"2010","value":"4848.40"},
    {"year":"2011","value":"5654.80"},
    {"year":"2012","value":"6071.50"}
]';

$jsonArray = json_decode($json);

foreach($jsonArray as $key => &$subArray)
{
    $subArray->value = (float) $subArray->value;
}

echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

with `preg_replace`

```
$json = preg_replace('/"value":"(\d+\.\d+)"/', '"value":$1',$json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

**Option 1.**

In the backend of your application (the php code) you can cast "value" to be float. E.g.:

```
$floatValue = (float) $strValue;
```

**Option 2.**

If you can't edit the backend use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) on each "value". It will produce floats from the strings in your response.